# TinyMCE considers `span` within `h1` to be invalid HTML

Tags: html, xhtml, tinymce

TinyMCE automatically strips invalid nested tags. This is usually OK as long as you stick to strict valid HTML.

However it's stripping `<span>` tags that are nested in my `<h1>` headers. This:

```
<h1><span>Hello</span> World</h1>
```

should be perfectly valid no?

Can I prevent TinyMCE from stripping this tag?

Comment: Yes, it's valid. (In HTML4, H1 has inline content. In HTML5, phrasing content.) So TinyMCE has it wrong. Not sure how to deal with this though. File a bug report?

Comment: This is only one of many reasons (as well as possible insanity) that I have written my own Rich Editor.